# TCPDF ERROR; undefined offset

Tags: php, html, undefined, offset, tcpdf

I am new to php and html.I am currently developing a functioning bookstore website.In it the administrator needs to beable to download a pdf of the customer list. i have used the tcpdf library however i ran into an error while using it. The error indicates an undefined offset withing the library while using the writeHTML function. Please note this is the code for after you press the create pdf button. line67 writeHTML() gives an error of
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp64\www\pdf2\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17161 , 17528, 17981,17981, 18279, 17981, 18288, 18290, 17528,17528 –

```
if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))
{
    require_once("tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P',PDF_UNIT,PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,true,"UTF-8",false);
$obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$obj_pdf->SetTitle("Customer List");
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData("","", PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN,"",PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$obj_pdf->SetFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA,"",PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT,'5',PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$obj_pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$obj_pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE,10);
$obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica',"",12);

$content="";
$content.='
    <h3 align="center"> Customer List </h3>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th width=5%>cus_id</th>
            <th width=10%>cus_f_name</th>
            <th width=10%>cus_surname</th>
            <th width=15%>cus_street_address</th>
            <th width=15%>cus_city</th>
            <th width=5%>cus_zip_code</th>
            <th width=10%>cus_country</th>
            <th width=15%>cus_phone_number</th>
            <th width=15%>cus_email</th>
        </tr>
';

$content .= fetch_data();

$content .= '</table>';

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);

$obj_pdf->Output("sample.pdf","I");
```

Comment: Please specify the _full_ error message and point out the _exact_ line it refers to.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp64\www\pdf2\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17161 ,  17528, 17981,17981, 18279, 17981, 18288, 18290, 17528,17528

Comment: Please add all information to the question itself. Do _not_ add additional details in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: And: _please_ tell us what that line contains. We cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: its almost always an issue with your html (long time tcpdf user ). keep it as simple as possible, converting html to pdf is not easy

Comment: "* NOTE: all the HTML attributes must be enclosed in double-quote." look at your widths.

Comment: even with it in double quotes it still gives the same error

Comment: either keep simplifying the current html, or build up from new html.